# Getting a 1004 error when ending copy loop at a blank row

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am trying to copy data starting at a row with cell with value of "Depth (m)" and ending at the next blank row. The number of rows between these will vary and I have 400 spreadsheets to do this on.

The error:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub CopyDepth()
   Dim rownum As Long

   Dim startrow As Long
   Dim endrow As Long
   Dim lastrow As Long
   rownum = 1
   colnum = 1
   lastrow = Worksheets("Profile").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
   With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Profile").Range("a1:a" & lastrow)

   For rownum = 1 To lastrow
    Do
       If .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "Depth (m)" Then
          startrow = rownum
       End If

       rownum = rownum + 1

   If (rownum > lastrow) Then Exit For

   Loop Until .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = ""
   endrow = rownum
   rownum = rownum + 1

   Worksheets("Profile").Range(startrow & ":" & endrow).Copy

   Sheets("data").Select
   Range("A1").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste

   Next rownum
   End With
   End Sub
```

It works if change this line:

```
Loop Until .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = ""
```

to this:

```
Loop Until .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "Doe (Jane, corrected):"
```

Unfortunately, I can't use that because that text will vary as well from workbook to workbook.

Here I a sample of my data:

```
Big Lake
29 October, 2012
Joe & Jill
Blue [Big] Lake, Utah (USA)

OLD meter (#00314)
Depth (m)   T (deg-C)
0   31.21
1   32.64
2   34.70
3   36.76
4   36.92
5   36.92
6   36.12
7   35.47
8   35.05
9   34.32
10  33.96

Doe (Jane, corrected):
N: 8.0m
S: 8.0m
```

What I really want to copy is from Depth (m) down to 10  33.96 to a new sheet.  I have been picking at this for a while but can't get it. The debugger points to this line:

```
Worksheets("Profile").Range(startrow & ":" & endrow).Copy
```

Any assistance would be great. Thanks you! -susan

Comment: Where do you have this code? In a module or a sheet?

Comment: 400 spreadsheets.... will make you cheese spread if you do not intend to optimize your code ;)

Comment: It's usually a seriously bad idea in a `For` loop to change the value of the counter used in the loop - `rownum` in this case. I'm not sure why you even have a `For` loop as the `Do` loop seems sufficient on its own

Comment: Well I'm not much of a programmer as you can see, so I was just finding code and hacking it together.

Comment: The code is in a module, should it be somewhere else?

Comment: barrowc, I based it on this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/927931/1864434

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only referencing row numbers in this line:

```
Worksheets("Profile").Range(startrow & ":" & endrow).Copy
```

Try changing that to:

```
Worksheets("Profile").Range("A" & startrow & ":B" & endrow).Copy
```

Change the column letters to the appropriate columns for your requirements.

**EDIT:**
Correct you are, the answer I gave before was an unnecessary change.  What was happening is you were referencing the startrow variable before instantiating it because your `Do ... Loop` would only run until the first blank line (line 5), whereas the "Depth" test didn't occur until line 7 (thus, the `startrow = rownum` line was never run).  So, in the Copy action, you were telling it to copy starting at Row 0.  You can fix this by correcting the placement of your `Next rownum` statement like so:

```
Sub CopyDepth()
   Dim rownum As Long

   Dim startrow As Long
   Dim endrow As Long
   Dim lastrow As Long
   rownum = 1
   colnum = 1
   lastrow = Worksheets("Profile").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
   With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Profile").Range("a1:a" & lastrow)

   For rownum = 1 To lastrow
     Do
       If .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "Depth (m)" Then
          startrow = rownum
       End If

       rownum = rownum + 1

       If (rownum > lastrow) Then Exit For

     Loop Until .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = ""
     endrow = rownum
     rownum = rownum + 1
   Next rownum

   Worksheets("Profile").Range(startrow & ":" & endrow).Copy
   Worksheets("data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
   End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
Sub CopyDepth()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets("Profile")
    Set rng = ws.UsedRange.Find(What:="Depth (m)")
    Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
    Worksheets("data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

As long as the blank row (in this example in row 19) is truly blank, this should do the job.

Comment: The number of columns will vary as well as the number of rows.

Comment: Hi Kevin - I just tried your solution and am still getting the 1004 error.

Comment: Kevin! This is very close... it grabs everything from "Depth (m)" down to the blank row after "S: 8.0m". Is there anyway to stop it at the blank row between "10  33.96" and "Doe (Jane, corrected):" I cannot tell you how much I appreciate your assistance! -s

Comment: That's interesting - when run on my computer it does just that.  Can you confirm that the blank row where it should be stopping is actually blank?  (meaning no spaces or other non-visible characters)

Comment: I just inserted a new row in that where the blank should be and it still went past it.

Comment: I tried your macro on another Excel file and I'm getting the 1004 error again... I'm beginning to think there is too much variability between these Excel files for a macro to really work. This copy process may just have to be done manually.

Comment: Interesting.  Try taking out the second instance of `rownum = rownum + 1` - it looks like that was done 3 times in some loops (one for the `For` and then two instances of iteration.  Working on some better code now.

Comment: Interesting I took out the second instance of rownum = rownum + 1 and that worked on some files but not on others.

Comment: Yeah, there is still a double-increment in there for some states of the loop.  I edited my answer with a 'better' answer, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: That is fantastic, it's working like a champ!! And so elegant too! Thanks sooooooo much Kevin!!

Comment: Phew! :-) Glad I could help, but sorry it took so long.